# How to connect to a Locally Hosted Web Server using ssh

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

To give some background:

I have machine 1, let's call it env1 that runs Linux.
I have a Machine 2, let's call it env2 that runs Windows.

env2 hosts a web server that is only accessed using the local network Aka machines connected to my internet router. So only things like the phone, env1 etc...

env1 is accessible OTA(anywhere) through only ssh.

Now my goal is the access/connect to the web server that is hosted by env2 using only env1 or ssh of env1.

I do not want to tinker anything on env2, but can do anything with env1.

2 questions,

A) Is it possible to some-how tunnel through env1 and access env2?

B) If so what would be my approach? Using ssh? or something of that sort?

Comment: Just use "SSH port forwarding" when establishing the SSH connection to env2, e.g. from `localhost:8080` to `env2:80`. Then use your web browser on `http://localhost:8080`.

Comment: Would that be something that I have to do on my local router settings or my env2?

Comment: no you dont. Its an ssh command that forwards all traffic from port X of you localhost to port Y of a remote server. EXAMPLE: ssh -L localhost:8080:remote_host:80 user@your_ssh_server

Comment: So after that would I be able to curl something from the web server using 

curl  localhost:8080